# Performant aggregation where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find the number of users that were created in the three months since the last user was created. All grouped by state.

Here's a query that works:

```
select count(u.id) as numberOfUsers,
s.state
from users u
join states s on u.state_id = s.id
where u.creationdate > (
select max(u2.creationdate)
from users u2
where u2.state_id = s.id
) - interval '3 months'
group by s.state
```

However, it takes 100 seconds. Can someone get me a more performant one?

I wish that this worked:

```
select count(u.id) as numberOfUsers,
s.state, max(u2.creationdate) as lastCreated
from users u
join states s on u.state_id = s.id
where u.creationdate > lastCreated - interval '3 months'
group by s.state
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might perform better due to only doing one scan:

```
select count(*) as numberofusers,
       state
from ( select id, state_id, creationdate,
              max(creationdate) over (partition by state_id) - '3 months'::interval as cutoff
       from users
     ) x
     join states on states.id = x.state_id
where creationdate > cutoff
group by state
```

However, it will chew through a lot of work memory doing the initial windowing aggregation.

Hmm, maybe something more like:

```
with cutoffs as (
  select id, state,
         (select max(creationdate)
          from users
          where users.state_id = states.id) - '3 months'::interval as cutoff
  from states)
select count(*) as numberofusers, state
from users
     join cutoffs on users.state_id = cutoffs.id
where users.creationdate > cutoff
group by state
```

This is trying to tease PostgreSQL into doing a properly partitioned scan, but it's not really ideal. It still does a full table scan, but at least only one. A set-returning function that iterated through the output of the CTE and emitted the result of the outer query inside the loop would probably work best, since that would be able to utilise a `creationdate` index for each state.

Comment: Awesome! I modified your query a little and got 82ms. (vs 100000ms, that's just a few orders of magnitude)

Answer (score 2):

Just out of interest, how does the following query perform? I'm particularly interested in how Postgresql processes the innermost query (states table + scalar sub query).

There has to a compound index on users(state_id, creation_date) for this to work.

```
select s2.id
      ,s2.state
      ,(select count(*) 
          from users u 
         where u.state_id     = s2.id
           and u.creationdate > s2.max_date) as numberOfUsers
  from (select s.id
              ,s.state
              ,(select max(u.creationdate) - interval '3 months'
                  from users u
                 where u.state_id = s.id) as max_date
         from states s
       ) s2;
```

*edit* this is the plan produced for that query with 100,000 user rows against 3 states:

```
 Seq Scan on states s (actual time=4.033..13.949 rows=3 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1743
   SubPlan 3
     ->  Aggregate (actual time=4.636..4.636 rows=1 loops=3)
           Buffers: shared hit=1742
           InitPlan 2 (returns $2)
             ->  Result (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=1 loops=3)
                   Buffers: shared hit=12
                   InitPlan 1 (returns $1)
                     ->  Limit (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=3)
                           Buffers: shared hit=12
                           ->  Index Scan Backward using users_state_id_creationdate_idx on users u (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=3)
                                 Index Cond: ((state_id = $0) AND (creationdate IS NOT NULL))
                                 Buffers: shared hit=12
           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users u (actual time=1.095..3.693 rows=8425 loops=3)
                 Recheck Cond: ((state_id = $0) AND (creationdate > $2))
                 Buffers: shared hit=1730
                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_state_id_creationdate_idx (actual time=1.017..1.017 rows=8425 loops=3)
                       Index Cond: ((state_id = $0) AND (creationdate > $2))
                       Buffers: shared hit=107
 Total runtime: 14.017 ms
```

Comment: That performs really well (of course, my data is just random white noise). with 100,000 users rows it averages about 17ms whereas my solution averages about 180ms (and the OP's original, I don't have the patience to wait for). I'll add the plan into your answer, otherwise it won't be readable.

Comment: @araqnid, awesome! Thanks a lot for taking the time! I must say  Postgresql is slowly turning into the best database I have never used ;) I have to find a real project to use it on soon.

Comment: FYI: In our database, the above query took ~3 seconds vs ~80ms for the query I posted below vs 100 seconds for my original query. (Our table structure is a bit more complicated and doesn't have the necessary indices to optimize this query. I simplified the query a bit here.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the query that I used to reduce the time to 82ms:

```
with cutoffs as (
  select max(u.creationdate) as cuttoff, s.id, s.state,
          from users u
  join states s on u.state_id = s.id
group by s.state, s.id)
select count(*) as numberofusers, state
from users
     join cutoffs on users.state_id = cutoffs.id
where users.creationdate > cutoff
group by state
```

Thank you to araqnid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you determined which part of the query is slow?  Can you add indexing?  I'm no Postgres guru, but I suspect that if users is not indexed on users.creationdate, the MAX() function will have to do a full table scan.  Hmmm, it may have to do one anyway...

That said, here goes nothing!

```
SELECT u.numUsers, s.state FROM 
(SELECT count(id) as numUsers, state_id 
 FROM users
 WHERE creationdate > (MAX(creationdate) - interval '3 Months'
 GROUP BY state_id) u 
left join states s on u.state_id = s.state_id
```

Comment: The problem is that it's doing a full table aggregation of all users within a state for each user in that state. Also, this query actually won't work because you can't have an aggregation in a where clause.